# Machine needs F1 key to reboot, how to skip this?

Tags: linux, reboot

Each time the machine (Linux, RHEL) reboots, it waits for F1 key to be pressed in order to continue the boot process. How can I skip this ?

These are the message :`Node3 DRAM uncorrected ECC Error`,`Node0 HT Link SYNC Error`,`Node1 HT Link SYNC Error`,`Node2 HT Link SYNC Error`,`PRESS F1 To Resume`

I searched a bit on the internet, but didn't find an answer that is testable.

Comment: Exactly what message is displayed while the system is waiting for you to press F1?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Sorry for a late reply, These are the message :`Node3 DRAM uncorrected ECC Error`,`Node0 HT Link SYNC Error`,`Node1 HT Link SYNC Error`,`Node2 HT Link SYNC Error`,`PRESS F1 To Resume`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the operating system. It's a BIOS thing.

You need to enter BIOS just when you power up the computer with one of the following keys:

<kbd>[DEL]</kbd> <kbd>[F2]</kbd> <kbd>[F9]</kbd> <kbd>[F10]</kbd> <kbd>[F11]</kbd> <kbd>[F12]</kbd> depends on BIOS type, you should be shown the key that enters Setup during POST

Then go into the basic settings and change the setting for keyboard errors.

Answer (score 1):

These errors could also be caused by Bios and Firmware.  Depending on the system maker you could be running into a bios or firmware bug as well.

The easiest way would be to update the firmware and Bios from the manufacturers provided methods.  I know Dell and HP both have discs that will update an entire machine.  I am not sure about others, but they should have something similar or individual files that can be used to update components.

Comment: -1, you mentioned some possible causes of the OP problem, but have not addressed his question of how to skip (or presumably fix) the problem.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

With those errors, I'd say your motherboard is likely broken. They have nothing to do with what operating system you are using.

The easiest (most pragmatic) solution would be to simply **replace the motherboard** and possibly the RAM.

If you are willing to use a broken computer (I wouldn't be...), you may be able to go into the BIOS setup and disable the hardware which you are being warned about. But since the messages talk about the system RAM (`Node3 DRAM uncorrected ECC Error`) as well as apparently CPU hyperthreading (`Node0 HT Link SYNC Error`, `Node1 HT Link SYNC Error` and `Node2 HT Link SYNC Error`), I doubt that would be a viable approach.

Has the system by any chance suffered a voltage spike or anything along those lines?

Comment: Not that I know off! We see this problem on a batch of machines. It is a scary to think that motherboards of more than 10 machines are gone bad in a batch of 30 machines...